# Override Magnific Popup close method when using the open method

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I'm trying to override the Magnific Popup `close` method (as [outlined in the documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#how_to_override_some_function_without_modifying_the_source_files) and [answered here by the developer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238775/542517)). However, when using the `open` method to create the popup (rather than attaching to an element in the DOM), the `$.magnificPopup.proto` isn't accessible.

Here's my example of non-working code. As you can see, I'm trying to override the `close` method once the popup opens. The `console.log` fires when I try to close (either by my Close button or by hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>) but the box does not close.

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: '/path/to/file',
        type: 'ajax',
    },
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
                console.log('close override is working');
                $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
            }
        },
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            var m = this;
            this.content.find('.redbutton').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                m.close();
            });
        }
    },
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    closeOnBgClick: false,
    showCloseBtn: false,
    enableEscapeKey: true
});
```

How can I close the box?

Comment: what's being returned by 'this'? i mean i would assume it would work too, but did you log this and see if it is what you expect?

Comment: It looks to be the magnificPopup object, which is why this doesn't make any sense.